# display a json response

Tags: ajax, json, laravel, laravel-5

I have this json when sending json post request and fetching the return data

```
 $.post("/employees", {id:"3"}, function(response){
    if(response.success)
    {
        var branchName = $('#branchname').empty();
        console.log(response.employees);
        $.each(response.employees, function(user_no, firstname, lastname){
            $('<option/>', {
                value:user_no,
                text: firstname + " " + lastname
            }).appendTo(branchName);
        });
    }
}, 'json');
```

and in my controller, it gets the id and find record/records where $branch_no is equal to $id and get the column user_no, firstname and lastname and return those as a json response.

```
public function getemployee(){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $employees = mot_users::where("branch_no", $id)
    ->select(array('user_no', 'lastname', 'firstname'))
    ->get()->toArray();
    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'employees' => $employees]);
}
```

now it supposed to display the response as

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Firstname Lastname</option>
    <option value="2">Firstname Lastname</option>
    <option value="3">Firstname Lastname</option>
    <option value="4">Firstname Lastname</option>
</select>
```

but it display as

```
<select>
    <option value="0">[object object]</option>
    <option value="1">[object object]</option>
    <option value="2">[object object]</option>
    <option value="3">[object object]</option>
</select>
```

i got no error in my console and I think i fetch the json response incorrectly so any ideas, help, clues, suggestions, recommendations to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$.post("/employees", {id:"3"}, function(response){
    if(response.success)
    {
        var branchName = $('#branchname').empty();
        console.log(response.employees);
        $.each(response.employees, function(index, value){
            $('<option/>', {
                value:user_no,
                text: value.firstname + " " + value.lastname
            }).appendTo(branchName);
        });
    }
}, 'json');
```